# Retrieve data from more one entity to RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I have user and products entity, so I store all products together in categories. When a user added a new product I get the id from that product and store that id in user entity.

By this way, I know each user what products he/she added. I am retrieving data from the database and displaying it in my `RecyclerView`.
The problem is: 
I don't know if my way is a good way to get data from two entity, is there any other way to search easier like `where` keyword in `SQL`.
Second thing I am getting below exception when I retrieve data from products entity:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert an object of type java.lang.String to type model.Product

1. I init the RecyclerView.
2. I get all products which user he/she added.(here I have key and
   category products).
3. Then by that key, I retrieve data from products entity.
4. Then I put products in RecyclerView.

The data in User entity:

```
"User": {
  "email" : {
    "email" : "email",
    "hasLoggedInWithPassword" : false,
    "name" : "mohammad tofi",
    "products" : {
      "-KR5LcHGurDceOO5xP_a" : {
        "categoryName" : "OtherBooks",
        "key" : "-KR5LcGdnNfQ-L4NWmOp"
           }
         } 
      }
}
```

The data in products entity:

```
"Products" :{
 "otherbooks" : {
 "-KR5LcGdnNfQ-L4NWmOp" : {
      "brand" : "Albania",
      "category" : "OtherBooks",
      "condition" : "New with Tags"
    }
  } 
}
```

My Code:

```
private void initRecyclerView(View root) {
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_user_product);
        if (recyclerView != null) {
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        }

        listViewProduct = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(listViewProduct);
   findAttrOfProductUser();//**step two get all products in User Data**
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

   private void findAttrOfProductUser() {
           //here I get the key and category name for each product in user entity and send to getProductUser. 
                       getProductUser(value,value2);//****
                    }
                }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }

        });
    }
private void getProductUser(String categoryName, String key) {
        DatabaseReference devs = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products").child(categoryName).child(key);
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, userProductViewHolder>(Product.class, R.layout.user_product_list, userProductViewHolder.class, devs) {
            @Override
            protected Product parseSnapshot(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                Product productuser = snapshot.getValue(Product.class);//Exception
                return productuser;
            }

            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(userProductViewHolder viewHolder, final Product model, int position) {
                viewHolder.productName.setText(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.productPrice.setText(model.getSellPrice() + "");
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(model.getImageuri0()).resize(0, 200).into(viewHolder.productImage);
                // products.add(model);
            }

        };
    }

public class Product{
     private String brand;
     private String category;
     private String condition;
   public Product(String brand, String category, String condition){
       this.brand = brand;
      this.category = category;
      this.condition = condition;
   }
  //then I make get and set for this attribute and empty constructor.
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: In addition, can you reduce the code a bit? The problem is either in the way `findAttrOfProductUser` looks up the values **or** it is in how `getProductUser` looks up the product. If you can reproduce the problem with hardcoded values in the call to `getProductUser()`, it means you can remove `findAttrOfProductUser()` from the equation (and from the question), significantly simplifying your question.